# BackGround Task to trigger if any changes in the Action Center

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, background-task

I need to trigger my background task when the application added the toast notification to the action center. I have tried with `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger` and it's  not triggering the task when the application added the toast notification. 
Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.toastnotificationhistorychangedtrigger.aspx) is fired whenever the collection of toast notification history from your app changes on the device. Subscribing this trigger, will allow your app to get notified when:

- A toast notification is removed by the user from action center;
- A toast notification is expired and removed by the system from action center;
- A toast notification is delivered form your app, via push;

**Note: the only thing your app wouldn’t be notified for, is a local toast being popped/added, since it is not necessary to notify your app client about something it just did.**

So generally, an app can be notified with `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger` when the app’s collection of notifications is changed in any way that’s not caused by the app’s local client. If your application added the toast notification by itself, the trigger won't be fired.

Comment: I have used notifier.show(toast) to display the toast notificaton. If i close the notification from the action center it will trigger my background task. on adding the toast notification in the action center with this method will not triggered my task.weather i have to change the method of displaying toast?.If yes, what i have to change to trigger mybackground task of adding toast notification in action center.

Comment: @visnusrinivasan Adding local toasts won't trigger your background task as **it is not necessary to notify your app client about something it just did**. You can do what ever you want after you sending a local toast and there is no need to use `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger `.  Only when a WNS push toast is delivered to the client can trigger your background task with `Added` `ToastHistoryChangedType`.