# How to remove history change event of toast notification on actin button click?

Tags: c#, uwp, toast

I have 2 background tasks that trigger for toast notifications.

1. **ToastActivationTask**: This is a ActionTriggerDetail task. Triggered on action button click.
2. **TrackToastNotificationTask**: This is a HistoryChangedTriggerDetail task. Triggered when history of toast is
   changed.

I have 2 buttons on the toast, Yes and Not Now. When the buttons are clicked both the tasks are triggered as the button click also changes the history of the toast.

I can only see one of the two possible solution:

1. When the action buttons are clicked only ToastActivationTask is triggered. OR.
2. History of the toast doesn't change on action button click.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove history change event of toast notification on actin button click?

Unfortunately, we could not remove `HistoryChangedTriggerDetail`, if you have register it, it is by design. Derive from this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542952/7254781).

Subscribing this trigger, will allow your app to get notified when:

- A toast notification is removed by the user from action center;
- A toast notification is expired and removed by the system from action center;
- A toast notification is delivered form your app, via push;

If you click actin button, the toast will remove by default. so  [`ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and  [`ToastNotificationActionTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.toastnotificationactiontrigger) will be invoked at same time.